# Designing a radio frequency PCB with wireless communication

Tags: pcb, rf

Sorry the last post I had was not specific enough! I am new to designing a PCB for my project. The goal is to develop a radio frequency PCB that has power and radio sources that can perform wireless communication. I am very new to this. I have a lot of questions regarding how should I get started or even what software I would need to code for the PCB. Are there any videos/ tutorials that can help me get started? Some relevant examples will be great!

Thanks so much for your time!

Edit: I added a schematic (brianstorm of my thoughts) that explain what I am trying to do..[image] I am trying to measure the data (voltage) from the sensors and hoping to wire that with the PCB. But the goal is having the wireless communication and transmit the data. I was reading using maybe NRF24L01 Transceiver Module that might save me a lot rather then designing my own RF? (I'd need to design an antenna which I am not experienced with..)

Comment: Trouble is that you are asking guys who know if they can remember videos and tutorials that helped them years ago so, that probably isn't going to happen. So, then you might get lucky with someone who just recently arrived at their solution who can remember that learning curve but, are these guys the best to ask - are they sufficiently proficient with a wider knowledge to realize what you need? You are stuck between a rock and a bigger rock and probably your best bet is do the research yourself. The other problem is that asking for videos and tutorials is a shopping question (they get closed).

Comment: Sorry for that! I was just thinking to get some directions to get started and ask proper questions as I learn

Comment: Probably not the best site for formal tutoring.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest your first (or even your first few) PCBs designs not be RF PCBs. An RF PCB one where the RF is actually running through the traces on the PCB you design. Use a radio module instead and mount that to your PCB. That's why they exist.

In RF, everything matters...which is kind of a problem when your hands will be full learning new things without having to worry about RF.

Not only that, it sounds like you will be juggling a microcontroller as well. It's definitely a recipe for failure to try and juggle learning two things (general PCB and microcontroller), and then a third thing that's affected by everything. Just general PCB design or the microcontroller on its own is more than two handfuls already.

Comment: That seems a good plan! That will be actually my first PCB design! Is there any good example for a beginner? I am just seeking a good direction for me to get started during this time. I am hoping doing thing step by step. Eg. Looking into the power supply, radio module, add trace (transmission line)?, and wireless communication (which I was planning Bluetooth for it)... etc

Comment: Higher level protocols like true USB (not UART-USB bridges) and Bluetooth are also several levels away from where you are. You're best starting out with a PCB design using microcontroller MODULES (like  Nucleo-32 or something similar) just to get a handle on programming and PCB design. You could throw in a SIMPLE radio module (not a Bluetooth module) at this point too. Then move onto implementing a bare microcontroller onto a PCB yourself. Only after this can you even begin to hope to try something like Bluetooth (even via a module) or RF.

Comment: to give a starting point to OP in case he hasn't seen already, some modules like the nRF24l01 can interface with almost any MCU and have many channels to play around with. These are relatively cheap from Aliexpress or other sites

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to get a schematic first and might be it will explain better for what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: Would you take a look of my thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @steamrice The NRF has an antenna. Go for it

Comment: @DKNguyen Sounds good! Are there tips on how to select the chip? I learnt that using atmel (eg.atmega328p) for my projects depending on the pin number or bits. Are there more specific requirements that I should pay attention too?

Comment: @steamrice Not really. Just make sure it has what you need and you have access to the tools and are willing to work with it for a while...because you'll probably lock yourself in somewhat.

Comment: @DKNguyen NRF seems handy and it works very nice with Arduino (as I was looking into an online video). But if my spacing for the project is limited, say 4mmx1mm (max) for the PCB, NRF does not seem working? (or should I be looking into MEMS?)

Comment: MEM has nothing to do with RF. Also 4mmx1mm is smaller than even an average microcontroller. Re-evaluate what it is you need and what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

To implement radios, you need at least these skills

(1) understanding of Ground Planes, and how to locally provide the charge surges demanded by the Receiver and Transmitter and MCU and Sensors; for that, you need to understand the shunt-cap and series-resistor or series-inductor "L" filtering of VDD

(2) understand how an electric field can couple across a PCB; Howard Johnson stated the coupling OVER A PLANE will drop off by 1/Distance^3; you may wish to explore electric fields of various topologies: wire-wire, wire-plane, IC_lead-IC_lead, and become skilled at sketching Efields

(3) understand how changing currents can couple across a PCB, whether through air or thru FR-4, and how the presence of copper foil regions may be your key to RF success

(4) learn about dense rows of VIAS to strap top and bottom GROUND plane regions together, and how the via-spacing relates to wavelength and attenuation

(5) realize the noise floors will be 10^8 weaker than a 1 volt signal, for 1 Hertz (1 bit per second) data rates; thus about 0.01 microVolts peakpeak for ultra slow RF links; don't even think about those; oscillator wander will kill you; instead think about 10,000 bit per second links with about 1 microvolt PP coming from the antennas; or think about WIFI with about 100 microVolts PP from the antenna; notice HOW SMALL THESE RF Receiver signals are, compared to the +3.3 volts of your MCU clocks and I/O.